# Transposing JSON list-of-dictionaries for analysis in R

Tags: json, r

I have experimental data expressed as dicts of key-value pairs for each experiment. A set of related experiments is serialized as a list of these dicts in JSON. This is parseable in in R via the `rjson` package, but the data is loaded in a form which is challenging to analyze

```
data <- fromJSON('[{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}, {"k1":"v3","k2":"v4"}]')
```

yields

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$k1
[1] "v1"

[[1]]$k2
[1] "v2"


[[2]]
[[2]]$k1
[1] "v3"

[[2]]$k2
[1] "v4"
```

Attempting to turn this into a `data.frame` directly with `as.data.frame(data)` yields:

```
  k1 k2 k1.1 k2.1
1 v1 v2   v3   v4
```

clearly viewing the the sequence of key/value pairs across all experiments as a flat 1-dimensional list.

What I want is a more conventional table with a row for each experiment, and a column for each unique key:

```
  k1 k2
1 v1 v2
2 v3 v4
```

How can I cleanly express this transform in R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `l*ply` functions can be your best friend when doing with list processing.  Try this:

```
> library(plyr)
> ldply(data, data.frame)
  k1 k2
1 v1 v2
2 v3 v4
```

`plyr` does some very nice processing behind the scenes to deal with things like irregular lists (e.g. when each list doesn't contain the same number of elements).  This is very common with JSON and XML, and is tricky to handle with the base functions.

Or alternatively using base functions:

```
> do.call("rbind", lapply(data, data.frame))
```

You can use `rbind.fill` (from `plyr`) instead of `rbind` if you have irregular lists, but I'd advise just using `plyr` from the beginning to make your life easier.

*Edit:*

Regarding your more complicated example, using Hadley's suggestion deals with this easily:

```
> x<-list(list(k1=2,k2=3),list(k2=100,k1=200),list(k1=5, k3=9))
> ldply(x, data.frame)
   k1  k2 k3
1   2   3 NA
2 200 100 NA
3   5  NA  9
```

Comment: Like the plyr solution, since it can deal with the variables appearing in a different order for each observation. 

Call me paranoid, but I was worried about some observations not having some variables. Here is a variation that does not break even for very bad cases:

x<-list(list(k1=2,k2=3),list(k2=100,k1=200),list(k1=5));ldply(x,function(z) as.data.frame(t(unlist(z)))

Comment: I think a better solution is `ldply(x, data.frame)`

Comment: I'd always choose the plyr solution :)

Answer (score 4):

This is interesting. The easiest way would be to fix the Python code so that the dict can be transformed more easily.

But, how about this?

```
k1 <- unlist(lapply(data,FUN=function(x){return(x[[1]])}))
k2 <- unlist(lapply(data,FUN=function(x){return(x[[2]])}))
data.frame(k1,k2)
```

You will need to cast k1 and k2 into the correct data type still, but this should accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: A cleaner generalization if you have a lot of columns would be:

newdata <- lapply(1:length(data[[1]]), function(x) unlist(lapply(data, "[[", x)));
newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata);
names(newdata) <- names(data[[1]])

Comment: I clearly can preprocess the JSON to transpose it before loading, but the problem is that I don't view this as "fixing" it at all: a list of dicts _is_ the most natural way to think about this data. A dict of lists is just the more convenient way for row-oriented software to load it densely, not the best way to think about it.

And manually unpacking every entry is untenable. Bretonk's method, however, works. (I clearly need to better grok the meaning of `[[` as opposed to plain subset (`[`), among other things.)

Comment: My solution works for two columns, which is clearly what your question implied. If you have several columns, then of course you need to use a generalization, such as brentonk's method.

Comment: You're right—I misread that (without running it) as being a *row-wise* operation, requiring an invocation on every data element, not just on every column. More explanation would have made that clearer. Still, for large numbers of columns, the further generalization is useful. Thanks, both. If you want to add an explanation of the generalization over many columns I'd gladly mark it "accepted". I think that would be useful for future viewers, rather than keeping it buried in the comments.