# Importing data from a JSON file into R

Tags: json, r

Is there a way to import data from a JSON file into R? More specifically, the file is an array of JSON objects with string fields, objects, and arrays. The RJSON Package isn't very clear on how to deal with this http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/rjson.pdf.

Comment: Also similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260147/transposing-json-list-of-dictionaries-for-analysis-in-r.

Comment: Hi Shane, tried using RJSON. I'm interested mostly in the necessary data manipulation. Here's an example of a JSON file I'm working with.

example.json:

[{"winner":"68694999","votes":[{"ts":"Thu Mar 25 03:13:01 UTC 2010","user":{"name":"Lamur","user_id":"68694999"}},{"ts":"Thu Mar 25 03:13:08 UTC 2010","user":{"name":"Lamur","user_id":"68694999"}}],"lastVote":{"timestamp":1269486788526,"user":{"name":"Lamur","user_id":"68694999"}},"startPrice":0},...]

Comment: A caution: If the JSON file is truly large, apparently the .so or .dll libraries won't process it. A preferable format is NetCDF, but some organizations are not aware of this issue.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

First install the [`rjson`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/) package:

```
install.packages("rjson")
```

Then:

```
library("rjson")
json_file <- "http://api.worldbank.org/country?per_page=10&region=OED&lendingtype=LNX&format=json"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

**Update:** since version 0.2.1

```
json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
```

Comment: Note that the edit is referring to an update to the library, not to R. The update changes the last line of the previous example and you still need to load in the library as above.

Answer (score 110):

`jsonlite` will import the JSON into a data frame.  It can optionally flatten nested objects.  Nested arrays will be data frames.

```
> library(jsonlite)
> winners <- fromJSON("winners.json", flatten=TRUE)
> colnames(winners)
[1] "winner" "votes" "startPrice" "lastVote.timestamp" "lastVote.user.name" "lastVote.user.user_id"
> winners[,c("winner","startPrice","lastVote.user.name")]
    winner startPrice lastVote.user.name
1 68694999          0              Lamur
> winners[,c("votes")]
[[1]]
                            ts user.name user.user_id
1 Thu Mar 25 03:13:01 UTC 2010     Lamur     68694999
2 Thu Mar 25 03:13:08 UTC 2010     Lamur     68694999
```

Comment: Absolutely! Really easier to work with data.frames instead of lists when filtering results!

Answer (score 32):

An alternative package is RJSONIO. To convert a nested list, lapply can help:

```
l <- fromJSON('[{"winner":"68694999",  "votes":[ 
   {"ts":"Thu Mar 25 03:13:01 UTC 2010", "user":{"name":"Lamur","user_id":"68694999"}},   
   {"ts":"Thu Mar 25 03:13:08 UTC 2010", "user":{"name":"Lamur","user_id":"68694999"}}],   
  "lastVote":{"timestamp":1269486788526,"user":
   {"name":"Lamur","user_id":"68694999"}},"startPrice":0}]'
)
m <- lapply(
    l[[1]]$votes, 
    function(x) c(x$user['name'], x$user['user_id'], x['ts'])
)
m <- do.call(rbind, m)
```

gives information on the votes in your example.

Comment: `x$user$name, x$user$user_id` should now be `x$user['name'], x$user['user_id']`. Also, `m <- do.call(rbind, m)` might be a better way of converting the list to a matrix.

Comment: is there something like convertToDataFrame function for JSON (like there is for XML package) ?

Answer (score 16):

If the URL is https, like used for Amazon S3, then use getURL

```
json <- fromJSON(getURL('https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/my.json'))
```

Comment: PSA: getURL is in the RCurl pacakge.

Comment: Also, `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Protocol "s3" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Answer (score 4):

**First install the RJSONIO and RCurl package:**

```html
install.packages("RJSONIO")
install.packages("(RCurl")
```

**Try below code using RJSONIO in console**

```html
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
json_file = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isrini/SI_IS607/master/books.json")
json_file2 = RJSONIO::fromJSON(json_file)
head(json_file2)
```

Answer (score 3):

load the packages:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
```

I have had issues converting json to dataframe/csv. For my case I did:

```
Token <- "245432532532"
source <- "http://......."
header_type <- "applcation/json"
full_token <- paste0("Bearer ", Token)
response <- GET(n_source, add_headers(Authorization = full_token, Accept = h_type), timeout(120), verbose())
text_json <- content(response, type = 'text', encoding = "UTF-8")
jfile <- fromJSON(text_json)
df <- as.data.frame(jfile)
```

then from df to csv.

In this format it should be easy to convert it to multiple .csvs if needed.

The important part is content function should have `type = 'text'`.

Answer (score 1):

## import httr package

```
library(httr)
```

## Get the url

```
url <- "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=72bc447a&t=Annie+Hall&y=&plot=short&r=json"
resp <- GET(url)
```

## Print content of resp as text

```
content(resp, as = "text")
```

## Print content of resp

```
content(resp)
```

> Use content() to get the content of resp, but this time do not specify
>   a second argument. R figures out automatically that you're dealing
>   with a JSON, and converts the JSON to a named R list.