# converting json file to CSV in R

Tags: json, r, format-conversion

I have downloaded the business json file from yelp to do some data mining in it but the file is in json and I want it to be in csv.   The file contains the following format:

```
{
    'type': 'business',
    'business_id': (encrypted business id),
    'name': (business name),
    'neighborhoods': [(hood names)],
    'full_address': (localized address),
    'city': (city),
    'state': (state),
    'latitude': latitude,
    'longitude': longitude,
    'stars': (star rating, rounded to half-stars),
    'review_count': review count,
    'categories': [(localized category names)]
    'open': True / False (corresponds to closed, not business hours),
    'hours': {
        (day_of_week): {
            'open': (HH:MM),
            'close': (HH:MM)
        },
        ...
    },
    'attributes': {
        (attribute_name): (attribute_value),
        ...
    },
}
```

How to convert it to csv ?

Comment: i tried the following code but it give me errors:

Comment: is it suitable for you to use an [online converter](http://konklone.io/json/)?

Comment: I tried but no success

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean CSV? JSON is quite convenient to parse, you can easily load it in a dataframe with R and then save it as CSV if you still need to.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r) describes pretty well the way to import JSON with R. Once done, you just have to rewrite the data in a CSV file using `write.csv()`. Here is the associated doc : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html

Answer (score 0):

Packages:
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

Library (rlist)

I have had issues converting JSON to dataframe/CSV. For my case I did:

```
Token <- "245432532532"
source <- "http://......."
header_type <- "applcation/json"
full_token <- paste0("Bearer ", Token)
response <- GET(n_source, add_headers(Authorization = full_token, Accept = h_type), timeout(120), verbose())
text_json <- content(response, type = 'text', encoding = "UTF-8")
jfile <- fromJSON( text_json)
df <- as.data.frame(jfile)
```

Then from df to CSV.
In this format is should be easu to convert it to multiple .csvs if needed.

The important part is content function should have type = 'text'.