# R - load in large dataset issues (250MB)

Tags: r, bigdata

I'm trying to import a huge dataset (to do analysis later), but I only want 4 of the rows (they are categorized by utility, and I'm only interested in a few of them).

Issue is: the formatting is bizarre AND huge, and I keep getting errors about not having enough column names.

Formatting is as follows: Each row is a utility region, and each column is every hour from Summer 2015 to present along with its electricity usage, so there are a LOT of columns (the number of hours from 2015 to present x 2).

I've tried the following:

```
> data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",header=true,nrows=150)
Error in read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",  : 
  object 'true' not found
> data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",header=TRUE,nrows=150)
Error in read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",  : 
  more columns than column names
> data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",")
#cancelled here because it froze my computer

> data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",]")
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
> data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",")
Error in read.table("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt",  : 
  more columns than column names
```

The dataset I'm looking at lives here ("US Electric System Operating Data", https://www.eia.gov/opendata/bulkfiles.php"

Ultimately, I'm going to want to use the dates and electricity usage, so reading it in a usage form and converting from ISO time would be also be great - thanks!

Comment: `read.table` reads tabular files, not JSON. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r#2617823

Comment: Did you tag with data.table deliberately? It appears nowhere in the question body... anyway, I'll go ahead and remove it.

Comment: @HubertL I had no idea JSONs existed! Any favorite packages to manipulate them? This format is totally whacky. Thanks for the help by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
wholedata<-fromJSON(file="EBA.json")
print(wholedata)
wholedata_data_frame<-as.data.frame(wholedata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the library data.table or the library h2o

For using the data.table library(a fastest way to load big dataset) you only have to use the command fread instead read.table

```
library(data.table), 
data<-fread("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt")
```

Another option, maybe the fastest one, is to use H2O:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
data<-h2o.importFile("C:\\Users\\EBA.txt")
```

Sure that with this 2 codes you will be able to do it!