# Loading JSON file into R

Tags: r, json, twitter, eda

I want to insert this JSON file (twitter data) into R and want to make a list like this

[image]

but I am getting something like this

[image]

My JSON looks something like this (this is just an example)

```
[{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "RT @KazmiWajahat: Indian media including @CNNnews18 confirming Pakistan's retaliation at LoC forward areas with heavy firing and shelling w\u2026", "is_quote_status": false}]
```

Comment: lots of options  Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing data from a JSON file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonlite::fromJSON` to parse the JSON file

Example based on your JSON sample string

```
ss <- '[{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "RT @KazmiWajahat: Indian media including @CNNnews18 confirming Pakistans retaliation at LoC forward areas with heavy firing and shelling w\u2026", "is_quote_status": false}]'

library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(ss)
#  contributors truncated
#1           NA     FALSE
#                                                                                                                                       text
#1 RT @KazmiWajahat: Indian media including @CNNnews18 confirming Pakistans retaliation at LoC forward areas with heavy firing and shelling w…
#  is_quote_status
#1           FALSE
```

Here you end up with a `data.frame` consisting of only one row because of the minimal sample data you gave.

To take a slightly more complex example from the [`jsonlite` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html),

```
ss <-'[
    {"Name" : "Mario", "Age" : 32, "Occupation" : "Plumber"}, 
    {"Name" : "Peach", "Age" : 21, "Occupation" : "Princess"},
    {"Name" : "Bowser", "Occupation" : "Koopa"}]'
```

you can see how `fromJSON` parses the JSON string and returns a `data.frame`

```
fromJSON(ss)
#    Name Age Occupation
#1  Mario  32    Plumber
#2  Peach  21   Princess
#3 Bowser  NA      Koopa
```