# How to solve "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when trying to extract a list from json file?

Tags: r, json, tweets

I am not very experienced in R. I have a data in son format on a series of tweets. When I print them they look like this:

```
print(result)
#$in_reply_to_status_id
#[1] 1.002615e+18
#
#$possibly_sensitive
#[1] FALSE
#
#$created_at
#[1] "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"
#
#$truncated
#[1] TRUE
#
#$source
#[1] "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"
#
#$retweet_count
#[1] "0"
```

etc etc.

Now I would like to extract only the list of the dates of these tweets to export them in csv format, but when I try:

```
tweetdate=lapply(result, function(x) x$getCreated())
```

I get:

> Error in x$getCreated : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r/2617823). See also CRAN package [rjson](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/).

Answer (score 0):

without the .json file and the code to reproduce the error I'm not pretty sure if this would work but it could worth a try.

I suppose that `result` must be a `list` of `lists` with one item per tweet and several columns or items for each of the tweets with the fields you have named above (`in_reply_to_status_id`,`created_at`, etc etc.). However, when you do:

```
tweetdate=lapply(result, function(x) x$getCreated())
```

You are calling a function named `getCreated()` as if each item in the `result` object has an inner method to return the date in which the tweet was created (as if each item of `result` is an instance of a hypothetical `tweet` class and `created_at` is an attribute of it).

However, your `result` object is only a `list` with several attributes, so I think that you only has to call its `created_at` item:

```
tweetdate <- result$created_at
```

If `result` is a `list` of `lists`, you can obtain a `vector` of dates as:

```
tweetdates <- sapply(result, function(x){x$created_at})
```

Hope it helps!

Read more: I suppose that you are used to program in object-oriented programming languages, however R is not specially designed to that (you have [S3](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) and [S4](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html) classes if you want to specially try object oriented programming in R)

EDIT 1:
This edit is just to clarify the answer. Your current result object has the next format:

```
> result <- list("in_reply_to_status_id" = 1.00256e+18, "possible_sensitive" = FALSE, 
"created_at" = "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019", "truncated" = TRUE, 
"source" = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", 
"retweet_count" = 0)
> result
$in_reply_to_status_id
[1] 1.00256e+18

$possible_sensitive
[1] FALSE

$created_at
[1] "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"

$truncated
[1] TRUE

$source
[1] "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"

$retweet_count
[1] 0
```

To obtain the data of that tweet, you can obtain it using the first solution I posted:

```
> tweetdate <- result$created_at
> tweetdate
[1] "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"
```

Now, supposing you change how you read the data of reading the tweets from the .json file and you have a `result2` object that is a `list`of `lists` where each `sublist`is analogous to your current `result` object:

```
> result2 <- list("tweet1" = result, "tweet2" = result)
> result2
$tweet1
$tweet1$in_reply_to_status_id
[1] 1.00256e+18

$tweet1$possible_sensitive
[1] FALSE

$tweet1$created_at
[1] "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"

$tweet1$truncated
[1] TRUE

$tweet1$source
[1] "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"

$tweet1$retweet_count
[1] 0


$tweet2
$tweet2$in_reply_to_status_id
[1] 1.00256e+18

$tweet2$possible_sensitive
[1] FALSE

$tweet2$created_at
[1] "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"

$tweet2$truncated
[1] TRUE

$tweet2$source
[1] "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"

$tweet2$retweet_count
[1] 0
```

In this case, the `created_at` does not exist, because that information is stored in each `sublist`. To obtain the information of that field, you have to iterate over each `sublist` extracting the `created_at` field. The second code I posted do exactly that using the `sapply` function (see more about the xapply functions in this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/apply-lapply-rapply-sapply-functions-in-r/)):

```
> tweetdate2 <- sapply(result2, function(x){x$created_at})
> tweetdate2
                         tweet1                          tweet2 
"Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019" "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"
```

There is a third case that I didn't contemplate in my answer that is when several tweets are stored in a simple `list`:

```
result3 <- list("in_reply_to_status_id" = c(1.00256e+18,1.00256e+18), 
"possible_sensitive" = c(FALSE, FALSE), 
"created_at" = c("Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019","Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"), 
"truncated" = c(TRUE, TRUE), 
"source" = c("<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>","<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"), 
"retweet_count" = c(0,0))
```

This case is equivalent to the first one when you only have a simple `list`, so you can access the `created_at` field directly using:

```
tweetdate3 <- result3$created_at
> tweetdate3
[1] "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019" "Thu Jun 20 10:54:04 CEST 2019"
```

I didn't post the explanation before because it's maybe too long but would help to understand how R works.

EDIT 2: The link with the xapply explanation was in spanish, I change it for an english source.

Comment: Thank you very much! The: 

tweetdate <- result$created_at

worked but when I tried: 

tweetdates <- sapply(result, function(x){x$created_at})

I still got the same error:

Error in x$created_at : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Yes, that is because your `result` object is a simple `list` that refers to a **unique tweet**, so you must use `tweetdate <- result$created_at` (i.e. access to the `created_at` field of your `list`). 

The `sapply` code is in case that you have a `list` of `lists` in which each sublist refers to a tweet and have the same fields as your current `result` object. The `sapply` function would iterate over each sublist and return the `created_at` field of each sublist, hence returning the creation date of each tweet. I wrote that code only if you change your way of storing each tweet.

Comment: See the edit in the answer for more information, but to sum up in your current case you should use `tweetdate <- result$created_at`