# Exporting pandas dataframe to csv causes random line breaks

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to scrape wikipedia for data on some famous people. I've got no problems getting the data, but when I try to export it to csv there's always a few entries causing a major issue. Basically, the output csv is formatted fine for most entries, except a few that cause random line-breaks that I can't seem to overcome. Here is sample data and code:

```
# 1. pull out wiki pages
sample_names_list = [{'name': 'Mikhail Fridman', 'index': 11.0}, #will work fine
                     {'name': 'Roman Abramovich', 'index': 12.0}, #will cause issue
                     {'name': 'Marit Rausing', 'index': 13.0}] #has no wiki page, hence 'try' in loops below

# 1.1 get page title for each name in list
import wikipedia as wk

for person in sample_names_list:
    try:
        wiki_page = person['name']
        person['wiki_page'] = wk.page(title = wiki_page, auto_suggest = True)
    except: pass

# 1.2 get page content for each page title in list
for person in sample_names_list:
    try:
        person_page = person['wiki_page']
        person['wiki_text'] = person_page.content
    except: pass

# 2. convert to dataframe
import pandas as pd
sample_names_data = pd.DataFrame(sample_names_list)
sample_names_data.drop('wiki_page', axis = 1, inplace= True) #drop unnecessary col

# 3. export csv
sample_names_data.to_csv('sample_names_data.csv')
```

Here is a screenshot of the output where, as you can see, random line-breaks are inserted in one of the entries and dispersed throughout with no apparent pattern:

[image: Random linebreaks are inserted in one of the entries with no apparent pattern]

I've tried fiddling with the data types in `sample_names_list`, I've tried messing with `to_csv`'s parameters, I've tried other ways to export the csv. None of these approaches worked. I'm new to python so it could well be a very obvious solution. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Probably you are using `;` as a csv separator and the wiki text has `;` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia content has newlines in it, which are hard to reliably represent in a line-oriented format such as CSV.

You can use Excel's Open dialog (not just double-clicking the file) and select "Text file" as the format, which lets you choose how to interpret various delimiters and quoted strings... but preferably just **don't use CSV** for data interchange at all.

- If you need to work with Excel,use `.to_excel()` in Pandas.
- If you need to just work with Pandas, use e.g. `.to_pickle()`.
- If you need interoperability with other software, `.to_json()` would be a decent choice.

Comment: I thought it was a newlines issue too, but the breaks aren't happening on newlines, and plenty of newlines are incorporated successfully in the rest of the output.

Comment: I want to export it for analysis in R (which I'm more familiar with), hence ideally want it as csv.

Comment: I would suggest JSON in that case, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r